# jquery having one function finish before launching another

Tags: jquery, function

I have an onclick that runs two functions, I want the first one to run and finish, and on finishing start the next one.  I have it setup like this right now and they seem to run at the same time:

```
$("#animate_1").click(function() {
update_1_close();
welcome_open();
});
```

these are the two functions, I don't want to combine them, I have several of these and combining them would end up being very complicated

```
function update_1_close() {
$("#update_1").animate({
    "right": "175px",
    "width": "160px"
}, 450);
$("#update_1_caption").animate({
    "bottom": "0px"
}, 450);
$("#update_1_img").animate({
    "height": "107px",
    "width": "160px"
}, 450);
}

function welcome_open() {
$("#welcome_back_1").animate({
    "top": "345px"
}, 450);
$("#welcome_header_1").animate({
    "top": "35px",
    "left": "20px"
}, 450);
$("#welcome").animate({
    "height": "270px"
}, 450)
$("#stick_figures").animate({
    "top": "215px"
}, 450);
$("#update_1").animate({
    "top": "465px",
    "right": "175px"
}, 450);
$("#update_2").animate({
    "top": "465px"
}, 450);
$("#events").animate({
    "top": "645px"
}, 450);
$("#directions").animate({
    "top": "645px"
}, 450);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the 2 functions update_1_close and welcome_open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can't run at the same time -- but, they might run one right after the other without the browser having a chance to refresh between them.

I have no idea what the two functions do, but you might want something more like this:

```
$("#animate_1").click(function() {
    update_1_close();
    window.setTimeout(welcome_open, 1000);
});
```

That will run `update_1_close` and then, one second later, run `welcome_open`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the welcome_open as an argument to update_1_close and execute it once it is completed. Since you 're using jquery animate, check this out http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You are looking for the "complete" param.

```
function update_1_close( callback ) {
  $("#update_1").animate({
      "right": "175px",
      "width": "160px"
  }, 450, callback );
  $("#update_1_caption").animate({
      "bottom": "0px"
  }, 450);
  $("#update_1_img").animate({
      "height": "107px",
      "width": "160px"
  }, 450);
}


update_1_close( welcome_open );
```

Otherwise, if you know the time that update_1_close takes to complete you can use setTimeout (yet beware since you may end up with magic numbers everywhere, it seems to happen so already)